# Missing Sharepoint App Template in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sharepoint-online, visual-studio-2015

Trying to use Visual Studio 2015 Professional for SharePoint development. After installing the Office Developer Tools, it added additional templates to VS but did not include the "App for SharePoint" template as depicted on the tools web page.

**Image from tools web page showing "App for SharePoint" template:**

[image: new project window from office developer tools website]

src: visualstudio.com/en-us/features/office-tools-vs.aspx

**After installing office tools on my machine (missing "App for SharePoint"):**

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apps have been renamed to Add-Ins. "App for SharePoint" is now "SharePoint Add-In"

**Update (May 5, 2016):**

The newest Office tooling has another change. Here are screenshots of the different stages of the tooling.

[image: Original Tooling]

[image: Stage 2 Tooling]

[image: Stage 3 Tooling]

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Rob that SharePoint App became SharePoint Add-In that located below

> Office / SharePoint > Web Add-ins > SharePoint Add-in

Here, I would like to announce about **Update 2 for Microsoft Office Developer Tools** that you can download it from **[Visual Studio 2015 Missing SharePoint Templates](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/office-sharepoint-template-missing-in-visual-studio-2015/)** that enables you to develop SharePoint solutions and add-ins for SharePoint 2016 that includes

- create new Office add-in projects using templates specific to an Office application (Word, Excel, Outlook, and PowerPoint).
- support new Office features such as add-in commands, Fabric UI, and new functionalities in Office.js.

---

**Check Also**

- [Missing Office / SharePoint template in Visual Studio 2017](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/missing-sharepoint-template-in-vs2017/)
- [Missing SharePoint 2016 Project Template in Visual Studio 2015](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/missing-sharepoint-2016-project-template-in-visual-studio-2015/)
- [Missing office / SharePoint Template in Visual Studio 2013](https://spgeeks.devoworx.com/missing-officesharepoint-template-in-visual-studio-community-2013/)